# SwiftUI: How to loop through the various structs with various codes, using ForEach?

Tags: struct, dynamic, foreach, view, swiftui

Supposed, I have three structs named "s001", "s002", "s003". Is it possible to use ForEach loop, which iterate these structs, without appending them into array?

Below the sample code, looping only one struct (s001). Is it possible to use dynamic struct names like "s00+(index)" or something like that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {


var body: some View {
    ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) {index in
               AnyView(s001())

    }

  }
}

struct s001: View {var body: some View {Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)}}
struct s002: View {var body: some View {Circle().foregroundColor(.blue)}}
struct s003: View {var body: some View {Ellipse().foregroundColor(.yellow)}}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `AnyView` is possible but has performance drawback, so for the described scenario, as it should not be too many such structs, the appropriate approach would be to use something like view-factory-builder function, like below

[image: demo]

```
struct S00ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) {index in
            self.buildView(for: index)
        }
    }

    func buildView(for id: Int) -> some View {
        Group {
            if id == 1 {
                s001()
            }
            else if id == 2 {
                s002()
            }
            else if id == 3 {
                s003()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct s001: View {var body: some View {Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)}}
struct s002: View {var body: some View {Circle().foregroundColor(.blue)}}
struct s003: View {var body: some View {Ellipse().foregroundColor(.yellow)}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Asperi, but I would like to have up to 20 various structs in my app. So it will be an extremely long piece of code...

Comment: OK, accepted. :))) I've just looked for more elegant solution...